# Multiple methods to fill String Array Java Android

Tags: android, arrays, fill

Little question...
Whats the difference in output between

```
private String[] mStrings={
     "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/670625317/aam-logo-v3-twitter.png",
     "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/740897825/AndroidCast-350_normal.png"
}
```

and

```
jArray = new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject json_data=null;
image = new String[jArray.length()];

for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
{
    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    img = json_data.getString("Img");
    Arrays.fill(image, img);                    
}
```

Because the first method works perfectly with my ListView (image + txt).. second method is the one i really need because i do not want any static images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Arrays.fill(image, img);
```

to

```
image[i] = img;
```

Arrays.fill() fills the given array with the specified input - meaning all elements inside the array will be set to the same thing. In this scenario, it means all elements in the array will be the same url as the last Img value in the json.

Comment: Wow, didn't thought about that. Thanks! Very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

when you're calling

```
jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

the parameter you're passing to the constructor, 'result' is a json string which will be of json format. json strings have a different format. You can know about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp).

JSONArray() constructor is doing the parsing here.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is something static that you declared manually and which cant be changed.But the second code you mention is getting the data from JSON (which is probably coming from a web service).

In that case you need to customize your List adapter to work with the JSON and change it's size according to JSON Array's size.

Comment: This is my own code so i know the difference between static and dynamic but I really need to know how different the array would be.. comparing String[] image and String[] mStrings

Comment: The thing that you cant use a String array for the data coming from JSON because you create a String[] array which you cant change it's size after.That's why you better use an ArrayList<String> which will change it's size according to data it receives and so.And in this case working with JSON it the best that you use this.